# How to retrieve data from MySQL database using jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL database using eclipse.I am using the same code of JDBC as for a java application...but it does work.

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the code here..

Comment: I believe you are changing the `Class.forName` for mysql... check the exception that you are getting...

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // Setup the connection with the DB
  connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name", username,password);  

// Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database ; that's why we need to create one.
    statement = connect.createStatement();

// Result set get the result of the SQL query
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from TableName;");

    while (resultSet.next()) {  //retrieve data
        String data = resultSet.getString("column_name");
                   ...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your database connection is created successfully then apply queries to retrieve data from database. If your connection is not created then you need to  check you driver setting or mysql password setting.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name",username,password");

Connection class having method like 'createstatement()', with help of this we can query from database.

Statement statement = con.createstatement();
resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from tablename");

And finally retrive the data from the 'resultSet' object.